# Coupon System Order price update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I'm coding coupon system rails 5.2.3 .
But I have a problem. If coupon code is entered before payment, discount is applied. But I can't update the total price if the product is deleted from the cart.

Order Model: Every update calculating price

```
   def subtotal
    price = order_items.includes(:product).collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end
```

Coupon Controller

```
def check_coupon_code
    if @coupon = Coupon.find_by(code: params[:code])
      coupın = Coupon.find_by(code: params[:code])
      @order = current_order
      if @coupon[:redemption_limit] > 0 and @coupon[:active] === true
        @order.total_amount = current_order.subtotal - coupın.amount
        @order.update(order_param)
        Coupon.transaction do
          Coupon.where(code: params[:code]).each do |coupon|
            coupon.redemption_limit = coupon.redemption_limit - 1
            coupon.save
          end
        end
        @order.update(code_apply)
        redirect_to "/cart"
        flash[:notice] = 'Coupon Code Applied!'
      else
        redirect_to "/cart"
        flash[:danger] = 'Coupon Code Invalid!'
      end
    else
      redirect_to "/cart"
      flash[:danger] = 'Coupon Code Invalid!'
    end
  end
```

Order Item Controller

```
def update
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.update_attributes(order_item_params)
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end

  def destroy
    @order = current_order
    @order_item = @order.order_items.find(params[:id])
    @order_item.destroy
    @order_items = @order.order_items
  end
```

Comment: What are you presently doing when the coupon code is deleted? The controller does not contain any particular code for that case.

Comment: coupon code is not required to be deleted.

Comment: Apologies, I meant what code is currently run when a product is deleted from the cart?

Comment: added to the topic, the name order item controller.

Comment: It seems like the best way to do it would be through model level callbacks. However, before diving into an answer, could you please tell me what the relation is between orders and coupons in the database? Does the `order_item` have a coupon id attached to it?

Comment: I'm saving coupon code to order

Answer (score 0):

Based on our discussion in the comments, I'm assuming `order_items` have `coupon_id` as a field which is either empty(if no coupon code is applied), or contains the id of the code applied to `order_items`.

Now, updating the price of the order as per deletion could be done using a `before_destroy` callback in `order_item` model. You could do something as follows:

```
# order_item.rb

before_destroy :update_order_price

private

def update_order_price
  # Your logic to recalculate the order price
end
```

NOTE: Calling another model's methods from a callback on one model can be a bit difficult to maintain in the long term. In that case, you could use an event driven mechanism in case this app becomes really large

Comment: I register the coupon code in the order table.
Price is already updated when order item is deleted.
What I can't do is update the total_amount if the order item is deleted when the coupon code is added.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have some trouble in understanding. If the coupon is for amount x, you would want to remove a part of x proportional to the deleted order item's price? Could you please elaborate with an example?